# how to navigate to different screen(react native) from the native activity than the activity called native screen?

Tags: android, react-native

In react natice application I need to go from screen 1(React screen) to a native screen(Android activity) which return some result data but once data is return app should go to screen 2(React screen) back to screen 1 unless back button press on native screen. You can see image below to understand
[image]
I am using onActivityResult in native module to call the new activity and on result sending premise to javascript with data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that until now (that i found) is react-native-brownfield.
Take a look at: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-brownfield

The last commit at the moment is from 2021, i can't tell if the project was abandoned.